# Automaltcaly copy rows from one Google sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Google sheets that are tied to Jotforms. I would like to build a script that, when a submission is made, the contents of the newly created row are automatically copied across to another Google sheet, apending at the last row.

Can anyone help with the triggers and code that moves the data across and places it in the first free row.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at onEdit() functions. It will fire whenever a submission is made to the sheet. Then you can just get the active cell, and triangulate the rows data using a getRange() based on the cell that's active. Paste it into the other sheet and you're golden!